# Problem with CSS and Firefox acting different than other browsers

Tags: css, firefox

I have a weird problem I can't seem to figure out, I have covered the forums and even combined the CSS classes to see if Firefox would work with the :hover effect but to no prevail its just not working. It does work in IE and Edge but not firefox any help would be appreciated.

This is what we have:

```
.footer-social-icons {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 70px;
 margin-left: -170px;
}
span.social-icons{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
span.ourfacebook:before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: "\f39e";
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
span.ourfacebook:hover:before{
    background-color: #3d5b99;
    content: "\f39e";
}
```

Thats our CSS and now for the html

```
<div class="footer-social-icons">
<a target='_blank' href='$social_site_facebook'><span class='ourfacebook social-icon'></span></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.footer-social-icons {
 float: left;
 /*  margin-top: 70px;
margin-left: -170px; */
}

span.social-icon {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ourfacebook:before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: "\f39e";
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
span.ourfacebook:hover:before{
    background-color: #3d5b99;
    content: "\f39e";
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social-icons">
<a target='_blank' href='$social_site_facebook'><span class='ourfacebook social-icon'></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the result you want here?

Comment: could you provide testable demo ?

Comment: your .social-icons class didn't exist so I made it social-icon. Hover works in Firefox as long as the negative margin is removed, but still not sure what your intent is here.

Comment: The problem is the hover is not working in firefox it does in ie and edge but not firefox

Comment: @MrX the hover works fine...

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine with my firefox browser .. it could be the version of your browser is old try to update it.

Comment: I can not comment till I get 50 reputation